# How can I concatenate streaming audio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, webrtc, streaming

I have a webapp that records audio from the user's microphone. It sends the data to the server. The relevant code looks like this:

```
class Recorder {
  // ...
  setRecorder() {
    this.recorder = new RecordRTC(this.stream, {
      type: 'audio',
      mimeType: this.mimeType,
      recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder,
      timeSlice: 2000, // Interval to send recorded data
      ondataavailable: async blob => { // send the data to the server
        let seq = this.seq++
        let data = await blob.arrayBuffer()
        if(this.socket.connected) {
          try {
            this.socket.emit('audio', {
              id: this.id,
              seq,
              mimeType: this.mimeType,
              data
            })
          } catch (e) {
            console.error('caught an error', e)
            this.stopRecording()
          }
        }
      },
      sampleRate: 44100,
      desiredSampleRate: 44100,
      numberOfAudioChannels: 1
    })
  }
}
```

On the server side (Express.js), I send the data as it's received to any interested clients. Here's the relevant code:

```
app.get('/play', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      let id = req.query.id
      let mimeType
      if(!recordings[id]) {
        // ...
      }
      emitter // the EventEmitter that's handling this
        .on(`audio ${id}`, data => {
          if(!mimeType) {
            mimeType = data.mimeType
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mimeType})
          }
          res.write(data.data)
        })
        .on(`close ${id}`, () => {
          console.debug({type:'audio close', id})
          res.end()
        })
    } catch (e) {
      next(e)
    }
  })
```

The issue is that each chunk I get from the client appears to be a complete WAV file, and concatenating such files doesn't work. When trying to play such a file, you only hear the first chunk.

I've been searching for hours for information about how to concatenate the input files (or any other method that would result in a stream that can be listened to). It seems that there's very little information out there about this topic.

I've been looking in particular at `ffmpeg`, but despite its purported ability to concatenate files, it expects the files to all be given on the command line. I'm receiving streaming data, so I can't practically list filenames in advance; I would have to send multiple files in on `stdin`, but that doesn't work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I would think that concatenating audio files would be a common need, but I can't find any tools that are capable of doing it without knowing in advance all of the data to be processed. Or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: Did you find an appropriate answer? I'm stuck at the same level.